# When I center data, should I take the absolute value or keep the sign?

Tags: regression, mean, centering

When I center data, is it the absolute value that you use or do you keep the sign? For example: you have data (4,5,6) and the mean is 5. After centering, is the data (-1,0,1) or (1,0,1)?

Comment: You can center data (subtract the mean), but I've never heard of centering the mean. Could you clarify please?

Comment: Apologies, If you center data is the result the absolute value or keep the sign

Comment: Could you edit the question to make this clear? Keep the sign of what, the data of the mean? If you mean what I think you mean, then when centering you don't need to worry about taking absolute values of anything at any stage, but some clarity would be helpful.

Comment: Keep the sign of the result. e.g you have data (4,5,6) and the mean is 5. After centring the data, is the data (-1,0,1) or (1,0,1)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your goal. In general, when we talk about centering data (subtract the mean), we are doing so in preparation for doing something like fitting a linear regression on the data. Centering (only subtracting the mean) is a linear transformation and the resulting data has a mean of 0, both of which are convenient for calculating and interpreting the results of a regression.

Subtracting the mean and then taking the absolute value would eliminate both of these advantages: the transformation would not be linear, and the mean would not be zero. So the answer to your question is: no, you don't take the absolute value when centering.

On the other hand, perhaps you are thinking about making a statement about how the data varies about its mean. Or perhaps you're thinking of residuals -- where you subtract the prediction from the actual values. In that case we often square the residuals (MSE) or take the absolute value of the residuals (MAD), depending on your goal and the technique you are using. In either case, the results are non-negative.

Returning to the usual use of "centering", it's also often used in conjunction with "scaling" (dividing each data point by a value, after centering) as a part of [Normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)).

EDIT: As an exercise, take an example dataset and plot it. Then, center it (subtract the mean) and plot it. If you don't look at the Y axis, can you tell the difference between these two plots? Now take the centered data and take the absolute value and plot it. Does it still look like the original data (again, ignoring the Y axis)?

Comment: Centring the data for regression

Comment: I answered more broadly than your question, for the benefit of others.

Comment: I've edited to make more clear that the answer is "no". It might've gotten lost in the extra explanatory text before.